# In VSCode, how to import React through IntelliSense?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

In the image below, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> nothing happens.

I was expecting IntelliSense to add `import React from 'react';` to the top of the file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your best shot should be using snippets. You can either create one for yourself (here's the official [VSCode snippets documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)), or you could use an existing snippets extension (like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.ReactSnippets) one).

I Believe a snippet you could use would look something like so:

```
{
  "Import React": {
    "prefix": ["React"],
    "body": ["import React from \"react\";"],
    "description": "Importing React"
  }
}
```